# Principal Component analysis with netcdf data

Tags: r, dataframe, pca, netcdf, era5

I would like to run PCA for different variables from ERA5. I have 4 different variables, 30 years of hourly data and longitude, latitude. How should I transform the data to run PCA?

Comment: It depends on which PCA function you want to run. With FactoMineR according to what you wrote, you can use your dataframe as it stands (variable in columns, recordings in rows)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to use the prcomp from the stats packege in r.

Comment: converting a large 3d data cube to a data frame would be very inefficient. I would suggest using one of the xarray-based modules in python (e.g. xmca) to perform the PCA directly on the 3d cube.